# Constant non-modifying object reference in PHP

Tags: php, oop

**This is not a question about real code, it is just for discussion.** It looks to me that it would be nice  to be able to pass an object as a constant reference.

```
$c = Coordinate;
unsafe_func($c); // this should be ok
unsafe_func(... constant reference ... $c); // this should fail on write to $c
```

I know about an option to pass a clone of the object like `set(clone $c)` which will keep my original `$c` not modified by `unsafe_func()`, but what if I would like to have a single object instance?

What I came up with is a wrapper class (code: https://gist.github.com/904897) using `__set()` and `__get()` magic methods, throwing exception on every `__set()` call. It allows me to do this:

```
class CoordinateConst extends stdConst {};
unsafe_func(new CoordinateConst($c)); // exception: can not be modified!
```

What I do not like about the solution is that by introducing CoordinateConst, I have to remove Coordinate typehints. But if I extend Coordinate class, `__set()` method is not called for visible properties.

The question: Is there a more common way to do this or would you rather avoid such code for any case (by passing object clone, wrapping unsafe_func call or something else)?

Comment: My thoughts on the subject: An object should take care of itself. If the object allows modification of its internal state, it needs to take care that these modifications are allowed and the internal state stays consistent. So that's not really the problem you're trying to solve. Your "unsafe" function seems to make changes that are not wanted in the overall program flow. As such, I'd say the function is broken and needs fixing. In this situation you shouldn't try to work around side effects the function has on other code, you should rather fix those side effects.

Comment: Cont.: I know this is for the sake of discussion, so that's just my 2 cents. Just saying you probably won't ever need a solution like this. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You solution effectively prevents public properties from being written to. The coordinate would not be a constant reference if it had a function such as:

```
public function setX($x) {
    $this->x = $x;
}
```

---

An alternative (but more code depending on how often you want to do it), would be to create ReadOnly versions of the classes.

I know in Java and C# it's commonly applied to Collections. C# has a `ReadOnlyCollection<T>`, which is just a wrapper/proxy, much like you have done there.

So my approach to the problem would be to create:

```
class ReadOnlyCoordinate { 
    private $coordinate;

    public function __construct(Coordinate $coordinate) {
        $this->coordinate = $coordinate;
    }

    public function getX() {
        return $this->coordinate->getX();
    }
```

Of course, you could extend Coordinate, and then throw Exceptions on functions that set any properties.

---

Then looking at the issue overall, if you don't want Coordinate members/setters to be exposed to `unsafe_func`, then perhaps you could only send the required data. Which does of course depend on how much of the Coordinate data it requires.

e.g.

```
unsafe_func($coordinate->getRequiredData());
```

but then if you have a lot of data it requires, it would become a hassle.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I tried to cut example code down, but yes if Coordinate has any public methods that are modifying the object properties, CoordinateConst (or your ReadOnlyCoordinate) must override them.

Comment: @Goran Rakic well ideally properties should be encapsulated, so there won't be any public properties to change. So public functions that set properties should be the only issue.